# Exception Handling Error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "odict_keys") to list

Tags: python-3.x

I was running pytest and using someone else's exception handling library. It supposed to run older version of python, not sure which one. However when I try to run it with python3, it spouted error that I didn't understand, also for some reason I have trouble finding the meaning of the keyword error (odict_keys) in the web.

The following was the result from the pytest. The exception handling inside test_analysis procedure was calling run_with_timeout(timeoutwrapper_analysis,max_seconds_per_call,(),{}) before the error occurred here. Inside run_with_timeout, the error happened when it raised e as an exception:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inputs,outputs,description", portfolio_test_cases)
def test_analysis(inputs, outputs, description, grader):
    """Test get_portfolio_value() and get_portfolio_stats() return correct values.

    Requires test inputs, expected outputs, description, and a grader fixture.
    """

    points_earned = 0.0  # initialize points for this test case
    try:
        # Try to import student code (only once)
        if not main_code in globals():
            import importlib
            # * Import module
            mod = importlib.import_module(main_code)
            globals()[main_code] = mod

        # Unpack test case
        start_date_str = inputs['start_date'].split('-')
        start_date = datetime.datetime(int(start_date_str[0]),int(start_date_str[1]),int(start_date_str[2]))
        end_date_str = inputs['end_date'].split('-')
        end_date = datetime.datetime(int(end_date_str[0]),int(end_date_str[1]),int(end_date_str[2]))
        symbols = inputs['symbol_allocs'].keys()  # e.g.: ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'GLD', 'XOM']
        allocs = inputs['symbol_allocs'].values()  # e.g.: [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1]
        start_val = inputs['start_val']
        risk_free_rate = inputs.get('risk_free_rate',0.0)

        # the wonky unpacking here is so that we only pull out the values we say we'll test.
        def timeoutwrapper_analysis():
            student_rv = analysis.assess_portfolio(\
                    sd=start_date, ed=end_date,\
                    syms=symbols,\
                    allocs=allocs,\
                    sv=start_val, rfr=risk_free_rate, sf=252.0, \
                    gen_plot=False)
            return student_rv  

        # Error happen in the following line:
        result = run_with_timeout(timeoutwrapper_analysis,max_seconds_per_call,(),{})
```

grade_analysis.py:176:

---

func = .timeoutwrapper_analysis at 0x7f8c458347b8>, timeout_seconds = 5, pos_args = (), keyword_args = {}

```
def run_with_timeout(func,timeout_seconds,pos_args,keyword_args):
    rv_dict = timeout_manager.dict()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_wrapper,args=(func,rv_dict,pos_args,keyword_args))
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout_seconds)
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        raise TimeoutException("Exceeded time limit!")
    if not('output' in rv_dict):
        if 'exception' in rv_dict:
            e = rv_dict['exception']
            e.grading_traceback=None
            if 'traceback' in rv_dict:
                e.grading_traceback = rv_dict['traceback']

            # Error occurred after the following line:
            raise e
```

E               TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "odict_keys") to list

grading.py:134: TypeError

Looks the script didn't like

```
 raise e
```

statement. What is that to do with odict_keys?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two of the inputs of analysis.assess_portfolio, symbols and allocs are in the forms of odic_keys. Apparently, this worked in python 2.7, however when running with python 3, they need to be in the form of list, thus changing the input statement from

```
symbols = inputs['symbol_allocs'].keys()
allocs = inputs['symbol_allocs'].values()
```

to

```
symbols = list(inputs['symbol_allocs'].keys())
allocs = list(inputs['symbol_allocs'].values())
```

fixed it